# Using selenium to click a button

Tags: python, html, selenium

For clicking a button with the following HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:submitPage('V','All Notes','');" class="viewFilter">All Notes</a>
```

I have tried multiple ways to click/ access this button but to no success, for example:

```
all_notes = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='javascript:submitPage('V','All Notes','');']"))).click()

all_notes = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//href[@type='class' and @value='View All']"))).click()
```

I am not really sure what the issue is here - for all other button presses on this webpage - selenium has been working appropriately. What other ways can I try?

Comment: Do you already use chrome devtools to test your xpaths?

Comment: Yes my chrome xpaths have already been working on previous button clicks earlier on in the code without issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all_notes = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@href="javascript:submitPage(\'V\',\'All Notes\',\'\');"]'))).click()
```

escape the single quotes

Comment: thanks but just tried, unfortunately, same error message as before: 'TimeoutException: Message:'

Comment: @Ossz updated the answer you should use double quotes for href value and enclose it with single quotes

Comment: just tried it and this works - fantastic thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this Xpath...

```
//a[@class='viewFilter' and contains(text(), 'All Notes')]
```

What this does is verifies that the class is viewFilter and since classes can appear more than once also ensure that the link text is All Notes.